# Why is Core Data not properly saving attributes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I don't know why Core Data is not saving my attributes properly. It saves the contents correctly, but it will not line up values (I have two columns). It gives me 16 rows instead of the 8 that I want. The "urls" column should be lined up with "album_names", and not pushed down.

Screenshot of sqlite file from simulator: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eObFV.jpg

The TBAppDelegate.h file:

```
@property(strong, retain) NSData *photoUrls
```

The TBAppDelegate.m file:

```
- (void)requestAlbums 
{
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/albums/" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     TBAppDelegate *delegate = (TBAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

     managedObjectContext = [delegate managedObjectContext];

     if (error)
     {
     }

     NSArray *collection = (NSArray *)[result data];

     for (int i=0; i < collection.count; i++)
     {
         NSData *album_names = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:collection];

         Everything *everything = (Everything *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Everything" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

         everything.album_names = album_names;

         NSArray *album = [collection objectAtIndex:i];

         NSString *photoQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/photos", [album valueForKey:@"id"]];

         [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:photoQuery completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
         {
             NSArray *photoResult = (NSArray *)[result data];

             self.photoUrls = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:photoResult];

        }];

         Everything *urls = (Everything *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Everything" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

         urls.urls = self.photoUrls;

         NSError *coreError;

         if (![managedObjectContext save:&coreError])
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", coreError);
         }
     }

 }]; 
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "line up" in relation to Core Data? It has nothing to do with your UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing 2 inserts (`insertNewObjectForEntityForName:`) within the for loop. Instead of inserting a new object you should update it with the url.

Give this a shot. Replace your second request block with the code below.

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:photoQuery completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
{
    NSArray *photoResult = (NSArray *)[result data];

    self.photoUrls = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:photoResult];
    everything.urls = self.photoUrls;

    NSError *coreError;

    // You can put the save somewhere else so that it doesn't get called 8 times in your case
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&coreError])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", coreError);
    }
}];
```